# Is this way of switching strings efficient? Are there more efficient ones?

Tags: c, string, performance, switch-statement

I wanted to make a program to switch multiple strings to avoid the if-else-ladder.

My idea was to make a linked list and to remove every node that is a different in some position. Then i could just return what argument it was and switch this number.

**My code**:

```
int str_switch(char* query, int arg_count, ...) {
    //Variables
    int i, j;
    struct node* args = (struct node*)calloc(arg_count, sizeof(struct node));
    va_list list;

    //va_list -> array
    int start = 0;
        //data
    va_start(list, arg_count);
    for (i = 0; i < arg_count; i++) {
        args[i].data = va_arg(list, char*);
        args[i].prev = i - 1;
        args[i].next = i + 1;
    }
    va_end(list);
        //start
    args[0].prev = -1;
        //end
    args[arg_count - 1].next = -1;

    //switch
    int len = strlen(query);
    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) { //i <= len: null character is also compared
        for (j = start; j != -1; j = args[j].next) {
            //remove from list 
            if (*(args[j].data + i) != *(query + i)) {
                //only one element in list
                if (args[j].prev == -1 && args[j].next == -1) {
                    start = -1;
                }
                //first element
                else if (args[j].prev == -1) {
                    start = args[j].next;
                    args[start].prev = -1;
                }
                //last element
                else if (args[j].next == -1) {
                    args[args[j].prev].next = -1;
                }
                //mid element
                else {
                    args[args[j].prev].next = args[j].next;
                    args[args[j].next].prev = args[j].prev;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //return
    free((void*)args);
    return start;
}
```

The `node` struct looks like this:

```
struct node {
    int next;
    int prev;
    char *data;
};
```

Small test program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main(void){
    char query[10] = "Horse";
    switch(str_switch(query, 3, "Bird", "Dog", "Horse")) {
        case 0: // Bird
            printf("It\'s a bird\n");
            break;
        case 1: // Dog
            printf("It\'s a dog\n");
            break;
        case 3: // Horse
            printf("It\'s a horse\n");
            break;
        case -1: // Error
            printf("It\'s an error :(\n");
            break;
        default: // ?
            printf("It\'s nothing..?\n");
            break;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**My question**: is this efficient? How could I make it more efficient? I want to know this because I may use this code in future projects and I don't want to lose performance because of some stupid mistake **:)**

Comment: `case 3` --> `case 2` ?

Comment: At the point where you need to call `calloc()` and use a custom structure to find a match for three strings, you are way off track. The allocation call is probably more expensive than calling `strcmp()` three times. And why the linked list when you preallocate, anyway?

Comment: It seems to be inefficient to reconstruct the data already on the stack into a list.

Comment: You might want to take a look at hash tables: They pretty much exist to perform fast lookup on complex objects like strings (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: This question is basically perfect as-is for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), but it's very off-topic here. Just make sure to include _all_ of your actual code that's related to `str_switch`, not a MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably build a data structure like a `set`, a `hashtable` or even a `trie`. Or a least `qsort` the list and do a `bsearch` to get the index. The biggest problem in your current code is that you're doing a lot of work on each call.

If your list of strings is known at compile time, you could even generate a perfect hashtable with [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/).

Another possibility is with [GTK+](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Quarks.html) which has a `GQuark` datatype that gives you a a 2-way association between a string and a unique integer identifier.